# R - fail to deploy on shinyapps.io - unsupported locale (greek: el_EL)

Tags: r, deployment

I am trying to deploy a local example-application on R's shinyapps.io (currently in beta, I suppose). I have installed the latest version of shinyapps package, in particular 0.3.64.

First I'm detecting the PC locale (windows) using the shinyapps detectlocale() function. el_EL is detected (this is acually my locale: greek).

Then, I run the deployApp function:

> shinyapps::deployApp('C:/Users/vaef/Downloads/ShinyApps/04_mpgAllVars')

**I get an "Error parsing manifest" error due to unsupported locale and thus my application remains undeployed:**

Preparing to deploy application...
Update application currently deployed at
http://vaef.shinyapps.io/04_mpgAllVars? [Y/n] Y
DONE
Uploading application bundle...DONE
Deploying application: 41592...
Waiting for task: 31035189
  error: Parsing manifest

############################ Begin Log ##################################

############################# End Log ###################################

Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 31035190 failed: Error parsing manifest: Unsupported locale: el_EL.UTF-8

I assume that el_EL is not yet supported - or has something to do with UTF-8? **ANY HELP?**